# MySQL - Query not outputting the right response

Tags: mysql

I have a table with friend1, friend2 and request, basically the end of the statement im trying to only output rows where the request is equal to p ... But it seems to be giving me an error instead.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friendfrom=8 OR friendto=8 AND request=p
```

The error message im getting is as follows:

```
Unknown column 'p' in 'where clause'
```

Can anyone please give me a bit of help ... Im quite stumped on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p is a literal, you need to use `'` marks to show that:

```
SELECT *
FROM friends
WHERE friendfrom = 8
   OR friendto = 8
   AND request = 'p'
```

Comment: I also had to put () around the friendfrom=8 OR friendto=8 ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Is  `p` a string? You probably want this:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friendfrom=8 OR friendto=8 AND request='p';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont write a string into single or double quote then it will treated as a column name of your table. that's why you have above error. so replace your query with this one:=

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friendfrom=8 OR friendto=8 AND request='p';
```